# @{} removing the vertical line for the header row of table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'd like to remove the horizontal spacing between the text and table lines. I am using @{}, but it removes the vertical line of the table for the first row. Does anyone know why?

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\columncolor{red}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{}}
\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | @{}c | c | N }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tabSummary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe `\rowcolor{mColor1}` is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix it! Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It removed even `\documentclass` ... `\begin{document}...\end{document}` apparently ;-)

Comment: `\rowcolor` has some overhang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to set `\tabcolsep` to zero then add space where you need it, this has some space in the outer columns, and tight space in the middle

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\columncolor{red}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{}}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | N }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{\ Author(s)\ } & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{\ Algorithm\ } & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tabSummary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If a column is left aligned, then I believe, I must set the spacing for all of the rows manually, Am I right? If you change `\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | N }` to `\begin{tabular}{| l | c | c | N }` then the second row is not alight with the first row of the first column.

Comment: @NESHOM you could use >{\hspace{1em}l} probably.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easier to define a new column type `C`

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}c}
```

and use it instead of `c` to obtain what you want, so you don't have to manually specify the spacing.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\columncolor{red}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}c}
\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | C | c | N }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \\ [0.5cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tabSummary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want to remove the spacing on the other side, as well, define it as

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}c@{}}
```

and you will get

[image]

Comment: @NESHOM You're welcome. Isn't it simpler this way?

Comment: sorry for the delay. Yes, generally it is easier, however, since I have already defined specific column types it makes it more complicated in my case to include this as well. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output (but you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{| c | @{}c | c |}[color-inside]
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} \\[0.5cm]
\hline
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{App.} & \textbf{Algorithm} \\[0.5cm]
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{tabSummary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]